# Terraform: Capture lambda delete events

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I have a lambda function that invokes via "aws_lambda_invocation" and with no inputs.

```
data "aws_lambda_invocation" "copy_config" {
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.copy_config_lambda.function_name
  input         = jsonencode({})
}
```

I'm trying to check the event type in the handler method.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        logger.info(context)
        logger.info(event)

        if event['RequestType'] == 'Delete':
```

But the "event" turns out to be empty. How can I check the event type (create, update or delete) inside the lambda handler function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what are these Delete, Create and Update types? Your `event` is empty because your input in an empty json.

Comment: Well, I'm new to terraform. But with cloud formation, I don't have to provide any. Basically I want to know whether the lambda function is invoked with the terraform is deploying, updating or destroying.

In cloudformation I do something like this,
  LambdaCustomTrigger:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource
    Properties:
     ServiceToken: !GetAtt <Lambda-Function>.Arn

Comment: I see what you mean. Terraform does  not support such thing. It also does not support creation policies for instances, update policies for ASG and many other things that you may use in CFN. Conversely, CFN also does not support many things that are possible in terraform. So both have limitations and they are not equivalent to each other.

Comment: Yeah I believe so. 
What will you do in this type of a situation? 
The Problem is, this lambda function copies files to a S3 bucket. But when deleting, bucket deletes before this lambda invokes and it results in a NoSuchBucket error.